# Apply focus to one object, after 10 seconds apply focus to another object, is that possible?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to perform a set timeout function with this behavior:

**Apply focus to one object, after 10 seconds apply focus to another object**, is that possible?

So I want to called it like

```
focustimeout([objectsarray])
```

where `objectsarray` is an array with all the id names for the N fields that I want to have a 10 second focus before each other.

I'm sorry for the question but in really new on javascript.

What can I add to this in order to get that solution

```
var temp = "id1";
var temp1 = "id2";
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#"+temp).focus()
    setTimeout($("#"+temp1).focus(), 10);
}, 10);
```

Comment: *"Is that possible?"* - yes. If that's all, then that should answer your question.

Comment: yes, it is... you just describe the solution, try to code it :)

Comment: hahaha sorry for that, I just add my current code :-)

Comment: No problem I just solved it function focus(array){
 $("#"+array[0]).focus();
 array.splice(0,1);
 if(0<array.length){
  (function (tempArray) {
   window.setTimeout(function(){focus(tempArray)},500);
  })(array);
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. Here is an idea how you can do it. Create function with 2 parameters, number of focused element and array of IDs which you want to focus.

```
function focus(i,array){
    $("#"+array[i]).focus();
    if(i<array.length){
    setInterval(function(){focus(i++,array),yourTime);
 }
```

Then call it from beginning `focus(0,array)`

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer that I needed, just one more:

In this case I get a loop of swaping between elements using focus, but i want that the focus just to be once peer array element, so Is there a way to add that maybe with a SetInterval Disable?

Comment: Thanks I just correct some errors on the function:

Comment: It's once per array, if you call it from first id of the array, it goes trought the array and when it reach its end, it does'nt call itself again. If you wanted it to go again and again, you have to add `else` block after the `if` and call the function with 0 to begin from first element again